# admob rewarded video not working or real id it works only on test id

Tags: admob

i tried to create admob rewarded video  for my application it worked perfectly on test app but it did't work on real one.is there any rules that admob put and i didn't know .dose it need time until the real id get activated

this are the codes that i tired and there is no error in it but the think is it work on test id but not real one 
    package com.example.median1.helper;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardItem;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener {
 private RewardedVideoAd mAd;
 private TextView mText;
 private Button Start;
 public  int credit=0;
 public int sum;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




  mText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);





        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(),"");

        mAd=MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
        loadRewardVideoAd();

    }
    private void loadRewardVideoAd(){


        if(!mAd.isLoaded()){

            mAd.loadAd("",new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void startvideoadd(View view){

        if(mAd.isLoaded()){

            mAd.show();
        }




    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {


    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {

        loadRewardVideoAd();

    }



    @Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
        mText.setText("now you can start");
         sum=credit+10;


        }



    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mAd.pause(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        mAd.resume(this);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mAd.destroy(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void start(View view){

 if(sum==10){

         Intent Nextpage=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Helper.class);
         startActivity(Nextpage);
 }else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please watch a video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be a matter of no fill error which means that google could not supply a real rewarded ad for your specific time of request (it depends mainly on Geo and advertising campaigns running In this Geo)

You should simply check the error code returned in the ad failed event:

```
@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
    // check the value of I and you will know the failure reason
}
```